# How to access Error Property after using cmdlet without loop

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get some information of an `Remove-Item` operation in PowerShell.

Since I don't want the loop to stop when one Item on `Remove-Item` failes, I can't use `Try{} catch{}` and `-ErrorAction Stop`

Is there a way to get error information i want without clearing the error variable before `Remove-Item`, and also without having to use a loop to iterate over the files?

```
$error.clear()
$Files | Remove-Item -Force
0..($error.count - 1) | % { 
    $x = $Error[$_].CategoryInfo
    $y = "{0}, {1}, {2}" -f $x.Category, $x.Reason, $x.TargetName
    $ResultLog += [PSCustomObject]@{Result="Error"; Path=$p.path; Message=$y}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-ErrorAction Continue` It won't halt the running of the script but will still add to the `$Error` variable.

To not have to clear the `$Error` variable before running, since the `$Error` variable is an array, simply store the Error count before running, and then use a `For` loop to only iterate through the new messages.

```
$ErrorsBefore = $Error.Count

$Files | Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction Continue

$ResultLog = @()
For($i=0 ; $i -lt ($error.count - $ErrorsBefore); $i++) { 
    $x = $Error[$i].CategoryInfo
    $y = "{0}, {1}, {2}" -f $x.Category, $x.Reason, $x.TargetName
    $ResultLog += [PSCustomObject]@{Result="Error"; Path=$p.path; Message=$y}
}
```

Comment: Careful, the $Error variable only goes up to 255 items before it drops off the oldest item and stops counting up.

Answer (score 1):

I like @HAL9256's gusto but I think using $Error.count is a bad idea. The count only goes up to 256 items before it stops counting up and starts dropping off the oldest errors. Depending on the volume of files and errors, you could easily run out of room there.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-error-handling-and-why-you-should-care/

Rather than using the pipeline, I think a foreach would be better suited.

```
$ResultLog = @()
foreach ($file in $files) {
    try {
        Remove-Item $file -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        $x = $_.CategoryInfo
        $y = "{0}, {1}, {2}" -f $x.Category, $x.Reason, $x.TargetName
        $ResultLog += [PSCustomObject]@{Result="Error"; Path=$p.path; Message=$y}
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah @duct_tape_coder is right you have to be careful about the 256 item limit. I was going along with the question where they wanted a non-`try..catch` method using the `$Error` variable. @duct_tape_coder does present the "Better" method which is to use manually iterate and use `try..catch` blocks to build your own array of messages.